# Unpublish packages from sinopia Local NPM registry

Tags: npm, sinopia

How to unpublish/remove already published packages in to Sinopia (Local NPM repository) ?

Let's say I have published a package called @test/test-package. How to unpublish it from local repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command.

```
npm unpublish @test/test-package
```

This will unpublish your latest version of this package. If you want to remove specific version, use version also.

```
npm unpublish @test/test-package@v1.0.0
```

This will remove version 1.0.0 of this package

Comment: Works perfectly.